# Route with Two optional parameters in MVC3 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have a following types of url used in my Application.

> ***localhost/admin/userdetail/id***
>
> ***localhost/admin/userdetail/id/true***
>
> ***localhost/admin/userdetail/id/true/success***

Here is my Admin Controller

> **bool inSaveAction, string status are optional**

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult UserDetail(string Id, bool inSaveAction, string status)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost, Authorize, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveUserDetail(UserDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        User userToSave = new User();
        AdminService.UpdateUser(userToSave);
        //This is calling the above function as it sending all 3 params
        return RedirectToAction("UserDetail", new { Id = viewModel.Id, 
                           inSaveAction = true, status = "success" });
    }
```

> ***Below case is not working***

```
  @Html.ActionLink("DisplayName", "UserDetail", new { id = Model.Id })
```

In Global.asax

```
 routes.MapRoute("UserDetail",
            "UserDetail/{id}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Admin",
                action = "UserDetail",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
         );
```

I followed http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

**How can i make inSaveAction & status as optional parameter for my UserDetail action?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the parameters in your route config. In order to make this work with different parameters optional (as in Phil Haack's post), you need to define multiple routes

```
routes.MapRoute("UserDetail-WithStatus", 
                "UserDetail/{id}/{inSaveAction}/{status}", 
                 new
                 {
                     controller = "Admin",
                     action = "UserDetail",
                     // nothing optional 
                 }
);

routes.MapRoute("UserDetail-WithoutStatus", 
                "UserDetail/{id}/{inSaveAction}", 
                 new
                 {
                     controller = "Admin",
                     action = "UserDetail",
                     // nothing optional 
                 }
);

routes.MapRoute("UserDetail-WithoutSaveAction", 
                "UserDetail/{id}", 
                 new
                 {
                     controller = "Admin",
                     action = "UserDetail",
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional
                 }
);
```

And then create links with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Index", "Admin", new { id = 1, inSaveAction = true, success = "success" }, null)
```

You'll also need to set the optional parameters as nullable, otherwise you'll get exceptions if id or inSaveAction are missing.

```
public ActionResult UserDetail(int? id, bool? inSaveAction, string status)
{

}
```

Comment: I Tried with the code you give. This also not working. Its not taking to the action method. Any problem in routing or action method params?

Comment: I just posted an edit, you'll need to make id and inSaveAction nullable. What's not working though? I tested this and all the routes work.

Comment: Thanks. status also optional only.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Can you verify the routes work? Set a breakpoint in your UserDetail action, and then try the urls /Admin/UserDetail/1, /Admin/UserDetail/1/true, /Admin/UserDetail/1/true/success. All should work, with the respective parameters set.

Comment: In all the cases i have to pass the Id. So can we remove the last route saying optional parameter?

Comment: You shouldn't need the id if you mark it nullable (int? id). The id = UrlParameter.Optional means that it's not required to match the route. So the last route will match /Admin/UserDetail and /Admin/UserDetail/id. One thing you might find helpful is Route Debugger. It'll show you which route parameters are being matched http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger

Comment: I didnot write Controller Name and page had erro,,,routes.MapRoute("MyRoute",
                "Learn14/{id}/{name}",
                new { controller="Home", action="Learn14"}); Why??