# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routes not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, maproute

Route

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Contact",
                    url: "Contact",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
                );
```

my controller

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

My Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
```

Finally my request url

```
http://localhost:1234/Contact/
```

Error on browser

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Contact/
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18033

What am I doing wrong?

**Solution:**

Custom route should take the precedence

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Contact",
                        url: "Contact",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
                    );
 routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "Default",
                     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                 );
```

Comment: where is your default route?

Comment: I do have it, just did not include here, thought not necessary.

Comment: It is, custom route should come above the default route.

Comment: oops. my bad. just realized it.

Comment: Good you solved it, I will post it as a answer.

Comment: @ssilas777 please do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Framework always tries to match the URL of the request to a `route` in the order of the Routes added to the `RouteCollection`

*So you should put the custom routes before the default route*,

```
 //Custom route
 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Contact",
                    url: "Contact",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
                );
 //default route
 routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

Comment: but then debugger stucks in the custom route and doesn't go to the default route on startup as well

Comment: @ZaveedAbbasi I don't think this can cause any issue, if you find any issues its better to raise an question with code samples.

Comment: actually i had at..... "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217271/mvc-routing-with-multiple-parameters-in-not-working/23217364?noredirect=1#comment35517982_23217364"

Comment: this solved my problem "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169796/route-with-two-optional-parameters-in-mvc3-not-working"

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use:

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*p}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", p = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
The asterisk indicates that it's a catch-all route. Keep in mind that these routes are extremely greedy, make sure that this stays below any specific routes.

You could also add a route constraint to this route which can determine whether the page exists in the database or something.
```