# .net mvc route default controller/action but not default parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcroutehandler

I created this route

```
          routes.MapRoute( 
                name: "Survey", 
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{surveyid}/{userid}/{hash}", 
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Survey" }, 
                constraints: new { surveyid = @"\d+", userid = @"\d+" } 
           );
```

When I then browse to

```
http://localhost:3086/Home/Survey/1/1/3r2ytg
```

It works, however if I browse to

```
http://localhost:3086/1/1/3r2ytg
```

it does not work.

If I then changed the route like so

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Survey",
            url: "{surveyid}/{userid}/{hash}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Survey" },
            constraints: new { surveyid = @"\d+", userid = @"\d+" }
        );
```

The exact opposite would work (and that makes sense).

But I am curious with the first route i thought both URLs should work since it shoudl grab the default controller and action when none is given.

**Update**

In the end I went with only this

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Survey",
            url: "{surveyId}/{userId}/{hash}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Survey" },
            constraints: new { surveyId = @"\d+", userId = @"\d+" }
        );
```

as that is the behavior I wanted. However when I then call

```
@Url.Action("Survey", "Home", new 
{ 
    userId = @Model.UserId, 
    surveyId = survey.Id, 
    hash = HashHelpers.CreateShortenedUrlSafeHash(@Model.SecretString + survey.Id.ToString() + @Model.UserId.ToString())
})
```

It generates

```
/Admin/Home/Survey?userId=25&surveyId=19&hash=2Norc
```

instead of a shiny path. I can force it with Url.RouteUrl but I thought it should have picked this one automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create route for each combination.

Check this **[Phil Haack Article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx)**

```
  routes.MapRoute( 
            name: "Survey", 
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{surveyid}/{userid}/{hash}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Survey" }, 
            constraints: new { surveyid = @"\d+", userid = @"\d+" } 
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Survey",
        url: "{surveyid}/{userid}/{hash}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Survey" },
        constraints: new { surveyid = @"\d+", userid = @"\d+" }
  );
```

Check this [Route with Two optional parameters in MVC3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169796/route-with-two-optional-parameters-in-mvc3-not-working)

Comment: Be carefull not to replace the default controller/action/id flow if you need it. If not feel free to use this.

Comment: Altho the question is answered I updated my post with a direct follow up, which would be interesting to know

Answer (score 1):

The routehandler doesn't really know that if you say /1/1/3r2ytg the 1 is for surveyId, the other 1 is for userId etc.
It just knows a path (localhost:3086) and x amount of "folders"
So if you call `http://localhost:3086/1/1/3r2ytg` he will map 1 to controller, 1 to action and 3r2ytg to surveyId.
It can't find userId or hash and since there are no defaults specified he can't find the route.
The defaults in your first route are pointless since they will never trigger.
Default values should be at the end of your url, which kinda makes sense.